# advice on the best method of positioning my active tab link correctly and consistently

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble trying to place my active anchor tab over the main content area border, i have tried adding position: relative etc but have had no joy, the tab also has to be positioned over the ul border so i think i may have set this up wrong, can anyone give me some pointers on how I could achieve this effect correctly?

My link http://jsfiddle.net/eBnUt/1/

Thanks
Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `margin-top: -2px;` to `.boxBody`. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/eBnUt/2/

```
.boxBody{
    border: 2px solid #343434;
    background: #fff;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    min-height: 70px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: -2px; /* add this */

    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```